# Out of memory on a 7696-byte file allocation while Parsin JSON data to string

Tags: android, json, out-of-memory

I am trying to handle huge data from webservice and there is no problem when I read data for 3 hour but when I tried to get data for all of day I took out of memory exception.Here is my code :

```
    @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            setInfo();
        }

    };
    (new Thread(runnable)).start();
```

and setInfo function:

```
private void setInfo()
{

        ReportAllActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                ringProgressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(ReportAllActivity.this, "Please wait ...", "Downloading Info ...", true);
                ringProgressDialog.setCancelable(true); 
            }
        });

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
              try {
                    String successMessage="";
                    jsonObject = new JSONObject();

                    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(URL);
                    HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
                    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams,10000);
                    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams,10000);
                    try {
                        jsonObject.put("data1",data2);
                        jsonObject.put("data", data1);
                        jsonObject.put("time1", "2014-09-05 00:00:00");
                        jsonObject.put("time2", "2014-09-05 15:37:00");

                        StringEntity stringEntity = new StringEntity(jsonObject.toString());
                        stringEntity.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));
                        httpPost.setEntity(stringEntity);

                        CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
                        cookieStore.addCookie(cookie);
                        HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
                        localContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, cookieStore);
                        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost,localContext);
                        HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();


                        if (entity != null) {
                            successMessage = EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity());
                            Log.i("Report All activity", successMessage);
                        }
                       jArray = new JSONArray(successMessage);

                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                    public void run() {

                                            fillTable(jArray);

                                    }
                               });


                    }catch (IOException e){
                        Log.e("Login_Issue", e.toString());
                    }catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();  
                    }
              } catch (Exception e) {

              }
              ringProgressDialog.dismiss();
          }
      }).start();

}
```

I don't know how to handle this problem. Here is m log cat : `

```
    09-07 14:05:18.296: E/AndroidRuntime(744):  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-07 14:05:18.296: E/AndroidRuntime(744):  java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
09-07 14:05:18.296: E/AndroidRuntime(744):  at android.view.ViewGroup.addInArray(ViewGroup.java:2027)
09-07 14:05:18.296: E/AndroidRuntime(744):  at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:1988)
09-07 14:05:18.296: E/AndroidRuntime(744):  at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:1865)
09-07 14:05:18.296: E/AndroidRuntime(744):  at android.widget.TableLayout.addView(TableLayout.java:418)
09-07 14:05:18.296: E/AndroidRuntime(744):  at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:1822)
09-07 14:05:18.296: E/AndroidRuntime(744):  at android.widget.TableLayout.addView(TableLayout.java:400)
09-07 14:05:18.296: E/AndroidRuntime(744):  at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:1802)
09-07 14:05:18.296: E/AndroidRuntime(744):  at android.widget.TableLayout.addView(TableLayout.java:391)
09-07 14:05:18.296: E/AndroidRuntime(744):  at com.example.example.ReportAllActivity.fillTable(ReportAllActivity.java:291)
09-07 14:05:18.296: E/AndroidRuntime(744):  at com.example.example.ReportAllActivity.access$1(ReportAllActivity.java:231)
09-07 14:05:18.296: E/AndroidRuntime(744):  at com.example.example.ReportAllActivity$3$1.run(ReportAllActivity.java:162)
09-07 14:05:18.296: E/AndroidRuntime(744):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
09-07 14:05:18.296: E/AndroidRuntime(744):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-07 14:05:18.296: E/AndroidRuntime(744):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-07 14:05:18.296: E/AndroidRuntime(744):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
09-07 14:05:18.296: E/AndroidRuntime(744):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-07 14:05:18.296: E/AndroidRuntime(744):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
09-07 14:05:18.296: E/AndroidRuntime(744):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
09-07 14:05:18.296: E/AndroidRuntime(744):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
09-07 14:05:18.296: E/AndroidRuntime(744):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

and fill table is here , I think this part is causing the problem;

```
private void fillTable(JSONArray jArray){


    int i = jArray.length()-1;
    for (int i = jArray.length() -1 ; i >= 0 ; i--)
    {
        System.out.println("fillll in table  ");
        try {
            json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);    
            TableRow tbrow = new TableRow(ReportAllActivity.this);
            TextView t1v = new TextView(ReportAllActivity.this);
            t1v.setText(json_data.getString("data1"));
            t1v.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            t1v.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            tbrow.addView(t1v);
            TextView t2v = new TextView(ReportAllActivity.this);
            t2v.setText(json_data.getString("data2"));
            t2v.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            t2v.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            tbrow.addView(t2v);
            TextView t3v = new TextView(ReportAllActivity.this);
            t3v.setText(json_data.getString("data3"));
            t3v.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            t3v.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            tbrow.addView(t3v);
            TextView t4v = new TextView(ReportAllActivity.this);
            t4v.setText(json_data.getString("data4"));
            t4v.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            t4v.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            tbrow.addView(t4v);

            TextView t5v = new TextView(ReportAllActivity.this);
            t5v.setText(json_data.getString("data5"));
            t5v.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            t5v.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            tbrow.addView(t5v);

            TextView t6v = new TextView(ReportAllActivity.this);
            t6v.setText(json_data.getString("data6"));
            t6v.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            t6v.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
            tbrow.addView(t6v);

            reportTable.addView(tbrow);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }  

    }
```

Comment: is above code in asynctask?

Comment: I have edited the post.It is in thread.

Comment: It is in two threads. Why are you using two threads? How often is it executed? Tell what your intention is first. Who is starting the threads again? What is the size of a response?

Comment: Why are you creating new table rows and text views all the time? Your report table grows and grows. Why should that be?

Comment: there are a lot of data and ı should report these datas.For every new data get from web service , new row is created and to categorize these datas new textView data is necessary,I think.